# logic behind deletion of duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, rowid

what is logic behind deletion of duplicate rows?
I got know this is the query which is used to delete duplicate rows.

```
delete from tvsemp e where rowid>(select min(rowid) from tvsemp m where e.ename=m.ename);
```

Here when I divided the subquery i.e first `select min(m.rowid) from tvsemp e, tvsemp m where e.ename=m.ename;`
Then I get result as the rowid is

```
MIN(M.ROWID)
___________________
AAAEDUAABAAAKiqAAP
```

Then for the outer query `select ename from tvsemp emp where rowid>'AAAEDUAABAAAKiqAAP'`
But for this I am getting n-1 results(except the one which I eliminated using '>' sin)

My doubt is if this two are combined I am getting exact table without duplicate why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking if the first query will work?

```
delete from tvsemp e
where rowid>(select min(rowid) from tvsemp m where e.ename=m.ename);
```

The answer is "yes".

As for how it works, your subquery is a *correlated subquery*, which basically means it references the outer query. Oracle executes the subquery for each row of `tvsemp e`, and the `e.ename = m.ename` in the subquery limits the subquery's results to rows where `ename` equals the `ename` in the outer query's current row.

Getting `n - 1` results is exactly what you want: if there are four rows with the name `Chay`, you want to delete three of them.

Put another way, if there are four rows with the name `Chay`, only one of them will have the minimum `ROWID` value. The `ROWID` for the other three will be higher than the minimum, so the `DELETE` query will delete them.

I hope this makes sense. There's more information about subqueries (including correlated subqueries) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries007.htm).

Comment: Thank you Gibbs that was helpful. Do you mean the corelated subquery acts as loops. i.e it will process each row upto the loop terminates with no row ?

Comment: There's a loop, but the outer query (`from tvsemp e`) controls it:  the subquery is called for each row in the outer query. It's hard to explain. The link I gave in the answer has some examples that may help.

Comment: ok No Problem will go through the documentation once. Thanks you